# DataGridView low preformance on backgroundcolor change

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, datagridview, background-color

I'm trying to set **DataGridViewRow** background color depending on days left or passed from DateTime.Now value. I have written easy static class which resolves dayleft/passed to color and return this color (**RowColors.GetRowColor(DataGridViewRow row**). This function i use to traverse all rows in DataGridView and change background color which returns my static class.

Everything works fine, but there is one small problem - performance. I got about 1000 of Rows and coloring lasts about 4 seconds. I know, thats not so much but i want it smooth and nice.

Moreover, when i add one row i have to wait 4 seconds cause of event fires. I used Parallel loop but it seems to be drawing problem. How can i do it faster. Thanks.

```
 private void allMatchesDataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {

            Color rowColor=Color.LightYellow;
             Parallel.For(0, allMatchesDataGridView.RowCount, i =>
            {

                rowColor =
                    RowColors.GetRowColor(
                       Convert.ToDateTime(allMatchesDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[CellNameTranslator.TranslateFromDatabaseName("DateTime")].Value));
                allMatchesDataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = rowColor;

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing one UI element parallel will not help.

Instead you should optimize your coloring code.

First: don't update while the DGV is in live mode!

- Call `SuspendLayout();` before and `ResumeLayout()` after the updates.

Second:

- Try to change only what needs to be changed. This will take some bookkeeping but that will be cheap in terms of performance.

Also, you just might consider checking out WPF, which will be a lot faster for any GUI work.

Comment: Oh god, i was so stupid!! I translated cellname from database, so every cell was checked against database and value was everytime the same. That was the main problem 4 seconds/700 records=0,005 seconds(that´s 1 sqlite query). Now it is briskly done. Thank you! Helpfull answer.